# EF extension functions

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4.1

i'm intend to use both Linq to sql and EF 4.x, in same project (for some reason),

but there are some stuff in EF, that IMO is "Weird" like this:

```
db.SomeTable.Where(x => x.Date > DateTime.Now.Date);
```

which must be written in this way

```
db.SomeTable.Where(x => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x) > EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(DateTime.Now.Date));
```

Is there any way, I can add functionalities to EF, or change this behavior, because LinqToSql don't have these weird syntax

Comment: Are you looking for a generic way to write that lamda or do you already have linq2sql lamdas written in the linq2sql way that you want to port over to EF without changing the code?

Comment: @StephenLacy I've already written code that targets LinqToSql, and I want it to work with EF, without any EF's specific syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it is possible to intercept the query and rewrite it. See the `IQueryable.Provider` and `IQueryable.Expression` properties. But this involves writing a custom `ExpressionVisitor` to translate the call and gets complicated a very quickly.

If this code above is the only mismatch between Linq-To-SQL and EF you encountered, you could rewrite the query like this:

```
db.SomeTable.Where(x => x.Year == DateTime.Today.Year && x.Month == DateTime.Today.Month && x.Day == DateTime.Today.Day)
```

I'm pretty sure that EF should support this comparison and so should Linq-To-Sql.

If you want to try the first solution, I recommend you create a `IQueryable<T>`-wrapper for the `ObjectSet<T>` returned by the EF and set a breakpoint when performing simple queries and see how the expression tree is actually stored within the query, this might give an impression of what to look for and what to replace it with.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to change the way that EF parses queries on the fly.

You can capture the queries on the fly and edit them using http://metalinq.codeplex.com/ however that might be a fair bit of work.

You can rewrite your query so it works on both though